# LWJGL Pojection view model matrices not working

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, lwjgl

I am new to OpenGL and I just begin to try LWJGL, everything worked fine until I added the PVM matrices, I don't know why nothing shows up when I added them.
The matrices related code is commented.
Here is the code :

```
public class Window {
    private int vaoid;
    private int vbover;
    private int vboind;

    private int vid;
    private int fid;
    private int pid;

    //private int pml;projection matrix location
    //private int vml;view matrix location
    //private int mml;model matrix location
    //private Matrix4f projectionMatrix;
    //private Matrix4f viewMatrix;
    //private Matrix4f modelMatrix;
    //private FloatBuffer projbuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

    public void start() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800,600));
            Display.setTitle("OpenGL Try");
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
         init();
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
             update();
             Display.sync(60);
             Display.update();
        }
        cleanUp();
        Display.destroy();
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Window displayExample = new Window();
        displayExample.start();
    }

    public void init() {
        //projectionMatrix = createProjectionMatrix();

        float[] vertices = {
                -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f,    // Left top         ID: 0
                -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,   // Left bottom      ID: 1
                0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,    // Right bottom     ID: 2
                0.5f, 0.5f, 0f      // Right left       ID: 3
        };
        FloatBuffer verticesbuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertices.length);
        verticesbuffer.put(vertices);
        verticesbuffer.flip();

        byte[] indices = {
                // Left bottom triangle
                0, 1, 2,
                // Right top triangle
                2, 3, 0
        };
        ByteBuffer indicesbuffer = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(indices.length);
        indicesbuffer.put(indices);
        indicesbuffer.flip();

        vaoid = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoid);

        vbover = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbover);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,verticesbuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0,3,GL11.GL_FLOAT,false,0,0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        vboind = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,vboind);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,indicesbuffer,GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);

        vid = loadShader("./res/shader.ver",GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        fid = loadShader("./res/shader.frag",GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        pid = GL20.glCreateProgram();
        GL20.glAttachShader(pid,vid);
        GL20.glAttachShader(pid, fid);
        GL20.glBindAttribLocation(pid, 0, "in_position");
        GL20.glLinkProgram(pid);
        GL20.glValidateProgram(pid);
        //pml = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(pid, "projMatrix");
        //vml = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(pid, "viewMatrix");
        //mml = GL20.glGetUniformLocation(pid, "modelMatrix");
        GL20.glUseProgram(pid);
        //projectionMatrix.store(projbuffer);
        //projbuffer.flip();
        //GL20.glUniformMatrix4(pml, false, projbuffer);
        GL20.glUseProgram(0);

    }

    public void update() {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        GL20.glUseProgram(pid);
        //viewMatrix = createTransformationMatrix(new Vector3f(0,0,0),new Vector3f(0,0,0),1f);
        //viewMatrix.store(projbuffer);projbuffer.flip();
        //GL20.glUniformMatrix4(vml, false, projbuffer);
        //modelMatrix = createTransformationMatrix(new Vector3f(0,0,0),new Vector3f(0,0,0),1f);
        //modelMatrix.store(projbuffer);projbuffer.flip();
        //GL20.glUniformMatrix4(mml, false, projbuffer);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoid);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,vboind);
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES,6,GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        GL20.glUseProgram(0);

    }

    public void cleanUp() {
        GL20.glUseProgram(0);
        GL20.glDetachShader(pid, vid);
        GL20.glDetachShader(pid, fid);
        GL20.glDeleteShader(vid);
        GL20.glDeleteShader(fid);
        GL20.glDeleteProgram(pid);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vbover);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL15.glDeleteBuffers(vboind);

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(vaoid);
    }

    public int loadShader(String filePath,int type) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int shaderId = 0;
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            String line="";
            while((line = br.readLine())!=null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        shaderId = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
        GL20.glShaderSource(shaderId, sb);
        GL20.glCompileShader(shaderId);

        return shaderId;
    }

       /* public Matrix4f createTransformationMatrix(Vector3f pos,Vector3f 
    rot,float scale) {
            Matrix4f mat = new Matrix4f();
            Matrix4f.scale(new Vector3f(scale,scale,scale),mat,mat);
            Matrix4f.translate(pos,mat,mat);
            Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rot.x),new 
            Vector3f(1,0,0),mat,mat);
            Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rot.y),new 
            Vector3f(0,1,0),mat,mat);
            Matrix4f.rotate((float) Math.toRadians(rot.z),new 
            Vector3f(0,0,1),mat,mat);
            return mat;
        }*/

    /*public Matrix4f createProjectionMatrix() {
        Matrix4f pm = new Matrix4f();
        float fieldOfView = 60f;
        float aspectRatio = (float)Display.getWidth()/(float)Display.getHeight();
        float znear = 0.1f;
        float zfar = 100f;
        float frustumLength = zfar-znear;

        float ysize = (float) (1/Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fieldOfView/2f)));
        float xsize = ysize/aspectRatio;

        pm.m00 = xsize;
        pm.m11 = ysize;
        pm.m22 = -((znear+zfar)/frustumLength);
        pm.m23 = -1;
        pm.m32 = -((2*znear*zfar)/frustumLength);
        pm.m33 = 0;

        return pm;

    } */
}
```

And the vertex shader :

```
#version 150 core

in vec3 in_position;

uniform mat4 projMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

out vec4 pass_color;

void main(void){

    gl_Position = projMatrix * viewMarix * modelMatrix * 
    vec4(in_position,1.0);
    pass_color = vec4(1,0,1,1);
}
```

And the fragment shader :

```
#version 150 core

in vec4 pass_color;

out vec4 out_color;

void main(void){

    out_color = pass_color;
}
```

Any help is appreciated ,that block me to continue learning the new opengl stuff, thank you.

Comment: So what do you expect this code to draw, with those parts commented? The correct output is an empty screen, because you leave the matrix uniforms at their default, which is all zeros, resulting in drawing two zero-area triangles, which are guaranteed to not generate any fragments.

Comment: I commented the matrices related code just to draw attention to them ,because nothing shows up when I have added them .Is the projection matrix at least loaded to the shader with the "gluniformmatrix" , or is the projection matrix syntax wrong ,I dont know.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed 3 problems.

1. You should use an IntBuffer instead of a ByteBuffer for the indices, because you store integers in this buffer. If you change the buffer type you need to also change GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE in glDrawElements to GL_UNSIGNED_INT.
2. Don't bind GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER to 0 after binding the indices buffer.
3. You don't need to bind and unbind GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER when calling glDarwElements

I hope this helps.